# Synonymize the tag [tfjs] with the main tag [tensorflow.js]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

[tfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfjs) should be marked as a duplicate of [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js).

Comment: Can you explain why this synonym is appropriate?

Comment: This user is the top contributor in these tags by a very long shot.  [tfjs] seems a very good way to get a hold of them though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hans notes in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403035/synonym-tags-tfjs-and-tensorflow-js#comment809496_403035) that, despite the apparent lack of thought behind this proposal, you nevertheless clearly know what you're talking about, being [the top user by a large margin](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tensorflow.js/topusers) for the [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) tag. (Thanks for your hard work there!)

Also, I reviewed the questions that were tagged [tfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfjs), and it was apparent enough to me (despite my own total lack of familiarity with this technology) that the questions using that tag were all about TensorFlow.js.

Therefore, I have gone ahead and completed the merge:

[tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) ← [tfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfjs)

As part of this process, [tfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfjs) was removed from 26 questions, and [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) was added to 12 questions (which were previously tagged only [tfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfjs) without [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js)).

Comment: Thanks. I should have added more details. Unfortunately being the only top contributors on the tag doesn't help  me to  project the tag. But I will be using the metastack whenever possible

Comment: Yeah, the tagging system isn't ideal, but it's the best we've got. Mods can always be reached on Meta for support with making big changes like synonyms, merges, etc. Also, do remember that you have the privileges to retag any questions as you see fit. (Maybe you're already doing this; I haven't checked.)